# Get the last lines of a text file within loop

Tags: python, file, loops

```
get_number = int(raw_input("How many bootloogs do you wish to upload? "))
```

I would like get the last lines of a txt file on user inputs. For example if get_number = 2 
The last 3 lines are redundant. I will get the 4th and 5th lines from at the end of text.

```
  first_log = file(file_success, 'r').readlines()[-4]
  second_log = file(file_success, 'r').readlines()[-5]
```

if get_number = 3

Then, I will need to add another line.

```
third_log = file(file_success, 'r').readlines()[-6]
```

get_number can be up to 9.

Finally, I will write this data to txt file.

```
   with open(logs_file, "a+") as f:
                f.write("===========================================")
                f.write(ip)
                f.write("===========================================\r\n")
                f.write(first_log)
                f.write(second_log)
                f.close()
```

How can I achieve that with loops ?

Comment: Should it always start from the 4th line from the last?

Comment: Yes @Haris. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your log file can fit whole into memory, you can just slice and reverse the lines:

```
log_lines = file(file_success, 'r').readlines()

with open(logs_file, "a+") as f:
    f.write("===========================================")
    f.write(ip)
    f.write("===========================================\r\n")
    f.write("".join(log_lines[-4:-4-get_number:-1]))
    f.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like this

```
get_number = int(raw_input("How many bootloogs do you wish to upload? "))
all_lines = file(file_success, 'r').readlines()

extracted_lines = []
for i in range(get_number):
    extracted_lines.append(all_lines[-4 - i])
```